# Convert nested dicts to list in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

In python I have a `dict` as below :

```
{'name':{0:'tom',1:'dav'}, 'age':{0:22,1:23}}
```

I want change it to this:

```
[{'name':'tom','age':22}, {'name':'dav','age':23}]
```

Can you answer with the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
>>> d = {'name':{0:'tom',1:'dav'}, 'age':{0:22,1:23}}
>>> values = zip(*[value.values() for value in d.values()])
>>> l = [{'name': name, 'age': age} for name, age in values]
>>> l
[{'name': 'tom', 'age': 22}, {'name': 'dav', 'age': 23}]
```

`[value.values() for value in d.values()]` return `[['tom', 'dav'], [22, 23]]` which's the values of your subdicts, and then, `zip()` return `[('tom', 22), ('dav', 23)]`.

Then, we use `for` loop over the zipped values, and put the values into the dicts in `l`.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant in one line:

```
a = {'name':{0:'tom',1:'dav'}, 'age':{0:22,1:23}}
[ dict(zip(*(a.keys(),y))) for y in zip(*(x.values() for x in a.values())) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

And Another one in one line ;)

```
age,name = {'name':{0:'tom',1:'dav'}, 'age':{0:22,1:23}}.values()
print [{'name': name[inx],'age':age[inx]} for inx in age]
[{'age': 22, 'name': 'tom'}, {'age': 23, 'name': 'dav'}]
```